# How can I create a view that could hold either an image or a video?

Tags: java, android

In my app, users can either take a picture or record a video. The file is then saved and its path is passed through an intent to the next activity, which displays it for editing.

My question is, how can I easily use the same view for either a video or an image?
I tried dynamically adding a view at runtime when I know what the file type is, but it turned out to be too hard to configure, not to mention the issues that VideoViews have with being rotated.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that using the same view would be preferable, since I'm not actually going to do anything to the contents that's specific to each kind of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both the ImageView and VideoView in your layout. Then set the visibility to GONE or VISIBLE for the one you want.

Comment: While that would work, I'd still have the issue of not being able to rotate videos in VideoViews.

Comment: If you need help with the rotation, you can post another question.

Comment: There are a lot of those, and the answer seems to be a unanimous "it doesn't work, use another view".

Answer (score 0):

You can create two child views, one for the image and one for the video. And depending on the type of your view you can hide/show your child views.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) for this

Comment: How would that help? Genuinely curious.

Comment: check my updated answer @LimEJET. i explained the same

Answer (score 0):

By using [frame layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) / Relative layout you can place a view on top of another view. After creating the views like i mention and using the visibility Gone & Visible you can manage to handle it..

```
 <FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

   <VideoView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:id="@+id/VideoView" 
      android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then based on your usage you can control it dynamically like below

```
   // register the views
   ImageView mImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
   VideoView mVideoView= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

 // check your conditions like show video view r image view here

 if(VideoView)
 {
   mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
 else if(ImageView)
 {
   mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: You wouldn't even need a special layout, technically. Setting one of the views to GONE and the other to VISIBLE would make the visible view take the removed view's place